# TableView height of rows not correct after setting

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I'm currently trying to load some cells into a tableview.
The cells getting added.. but the height is not correct.
[image: In Xcode the prototype-cell is shown as following]

[image: As you can see, the cells have the height of a default one.]

How can I get the cells to the height of the first picture?

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: As the picture suggests, you did not set up any constraints. You either need to work with Auto Layout or calculate the cell size manually.

Comment: @the4kman I added constraints to all elements in the prototype cell. Maybe there‘s missing some constraints on the prototype cell.. there, I couldn‘t set any constraints...

Comment: Are the images the same height, or will that vary?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon The images are always the same height...

Comment: So did you set your cell height to ImageView height + top margin + bottom margin?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon I set the row - height to 153.. in the Main.storyboard it shows up the right way...

Comment: You can try selecting the Table View and in the Size Inspector setting the row height to 153. Then doing the same thing for the Cell Height.

Comment: @D.Greg Thanks man! That was the problem!